# How to use woocommerce jquery trigger when custom script are declared before them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I create a custom wordpress theme based on https://flyntwp.com/ which is a component based starter theme (who also use Timber (twig)).

I tried to create a custom component for my woocommerce product page with variable product.
So I need to get which variation is selected by user, for that I have tried to used the woocommerce Jquery trigger like this example :

```
$( ".variations_form" ).on( "woocommerce_variation_select_change", function () {
    // Fires whenever variation selects are changed
} );

$( ".single_variation_wrap" ).on( "show_variation", function ( event, variation ) {
    // Fired when the user selects all the required dropdowns / attributes
    // and a final variation is selected / shown
} );
```

But it doesn't work because flynt call component JS script on header and woocommerce library are called on footer. :(

So how I can get around that and use woocommerce trigger?

(Note : I also tried to use another jquery method like this without using the woo trigger:

```
$('.variations select').on('change', function() {
  var inputString = $(".variation_id").val(); 
  alert(inputString); 

})
```

With this one I get the variation ID before woocommerce change the variation therefore I don't get the actual selected ID, but the old one )

I am a little stuck, what should I do? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Put your code inside document ready event (its fires when the page is fully loaded)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

       $('.variations select').on('change', function() {
            var inputString = $(".variation_id").val(); 
            alert(inputString); 

        });
});
```